# problems with angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular factory to share data between controller each controller is for one page. Here is my js file

```
app.factory('myService', function() {
    var savedData = {};
    function set(data) {
        savedData = data;
    }
    function get() {
        return savedData;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});

app.controller("logincont", ['$scope','$http','md5','$window','myService',function($scope,$http,md5,$window,myService){
    $scope.cari = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8089/MonitoringAPI/webresources/login?a='+$scope.userid+'&d='+$scope.password).then(function(response){
            $scope.reslogin  = response.data;
            $scope.reslogin2 = response.data.username;
            myService.set($scope.reslogin2);
            console.log($scope.reslogin2);
            console.log(myService.set($scope.reslogin2));
        });
    };   
}]);

app.controller("moncont", ['$scope','$http','$filter','myService',function($scope,$http,$filter,myService){
    $scope.user = myService.get();
    console.log($scope.user);
}]);
```

Here is the result when I call console.log
`console.log($scope.reslogin2) = ristian`
`console.log(myService.set($scope.reslogin2)) = undefined`
`console.log($scope.user)={}`

The result that I expected, ristian is filled each scope.

Comment: You log $scope.user when promise not resolve , this is why you get object when log $scope.user

Comment: how about the second scope? why i got undefined value not ristian.

Comment: because myService.set($scope.reslogin2) doesn't return anything so you got undefined , change to myService.get()

Comment: the third scope what should i do to get value ristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues here, some have already been addressed in the comments. Another of the problems is that your `set()` function overrides the `savedData` object reference. So when you call `myService.get()` you get the reference to the empty object, then when the http request resolved and `set` is called, whatever you've assigned originally, still references the empty object.

So in the above example, this is what happens chronologically (assuming you call `$scope.cari()` at some point in time):

1. `$scope.user = myService.get();` assigns a reference to the empty object in `savedData` to `$scope.user`
2. At some point you make a http request, that calls `myService.set($scope.reslogin2);`
3. This call to `set` overrides the reference in `savedData`.
4. `$scope.user` still references the old empty object.

To fix this particular issue, you need to either rethink your entire flow, or replace your set method with somethink like this

```
function set(data) {
    angular.extend(savedData, data);
}
```

which mutates the `savedData` object, instead of overrides it. This can cause other issues, with empty properties not being overriden, but that entirely depends on what properties are in `data`.

Comment: thank you, your explanation is very helpfull. thank you so much